# GitLab : Add Default Approvers Picking from a file

Tags: gitlab

I'm new to the GitLab and currently playing with the community edition.
I need to add a default approver per product, together with the user picked person.

I'm thinking of keeping the default account(s) in a repository-hosted yaml file.
And I found this comment which is much similar to my case:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/965#note_20414031

Can someone guide me to start:

- Is this doable with [Merge request hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#merge-request-events)?
- Or need to build a GitLab plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Settings > General > Merge Request Settings > Expand

[image: Merge request approvals]

Comment: PS : the `merge request approvals` is a premium feature

Comment: Answers the body of the question, but not the title. The approvers aren't added as reviewers, so the MR does not show up in the approver's "Review requests for you" section on GitLab